# Windows 7 laptop freezes up

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My wife's 3-year-old laptop has started freezing randomly, and I am hoping the folks here can help me figure out why.

## Symptoms

This started happening last week, around Wednesday or Thursday, and now happens within an hour or two every time I reboot.

It sometimes has a brief screen flicker -- the entire screen goes dark for approximately 0.5 seconds -- before it crashes, but not always. When it crashes, the primary symptom is that program windows and the Windows toolbar, including the system tray and Start button, stop responding to user input. If I am playing music or other audio, it generally keeps going, but everything else stops, as far as I can tell. Sometimes <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will continue to work, but no other input from the keyboard or mouse is recognized, even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and anything happening on the screen stops. Eventually, I end up having to do a hard reboot. (Edit: by this I mean holding the power button. I have waited as long as 30 minutes for the computer to "come back," but it never does.)

This has only happened when I am running Chrome (version 36.0.1985.125 m), and that's usually the first app to start acting up, but I'm not sure that's meaningful because Chrome is running 100% of the time. I also have a number of other constantly-on apps -- for example, Xampp, CrashPlan, McAfee, AutoHotKey, Evernote, Dropbox, and LogMeIn Hamachi -- but I don't believe any of them have updated in the last few days. It also happens whether or not I have external hardware of any kind attached.

## What I've Tried

I've tried all of the following, but none shows any anomalies or problems:

- Looked at the system logs
- Full virus scan (runs every week, plus real-time scanning)
- HijackThis (nothing out of the ordinary)
- Dell PC Checkup diagnostics on CPU, HDD, RAM, etc.
- Defragmenting my C drive while in safe mode (using Auslogics)

I have also run `sfc /scannow` and taken a can of compressed air to the fan unit with no luck.

Edit: I have also run a S.M.A.R.T. scan using CrystalDiskInfo; it reports no problems.

## System Info

The output of running `systeminfo` from the command line:

```
Host Name:                 SARAH-XPS
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium 
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Sarah
Registered Organization:   Microsoft
Product ID:                00359-OEM-8992687-00095
Original Install Date:     7/27/2011, 7:43:05 PM
System Boot Time:          7/30/2014, 5:30:39 PM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.         
System Model:              Dell System XPS L502X
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2701 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc.          A05, 5/4/2011
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     8,106 MB
Available Physical Memory: 1,511 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  16,211 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 8,307 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    7,904 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\SARAH-XPS
Hotfix(s):                 300 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB2849697
                           [02]: KB2849696
                           [03]: KB2841134
                           [04]: KB2670838
                           [05]: KB2830477
                           [06]: KB2592687
                           [07]: KB971033
                           [08]: KB2506143
                           [09]: KB2393802
                           [10]: KB2425227
                           [11]: KB2459268
                           [12]: KB2475792
                           [13]: KB2476490
                           [14]: KB2478662
                           [15]: KB2479628
                           [16]: KB2479943
                           [17]: KB2482122
                           [18]: KB2484033
                           [19]: KB2485376
                           [20]: KB2488113
                           [21]: KB2491683
                           [22]: KB2492386
                           [23]: KB2496898
                           [24]: KB2503658
                           [25]: KB2503665
                           [26]: KB2505438
                           [27]: KB2506014
                           [28]: KB2506212
                           [29]: KB2506223
                           [30]: KB2506928
                           [31]: KB2507618
                           [32]: KB2507938
                           [33]: KB2508272
                           [34]: KB2508429
                           [35]: KB2509553
                           [36]: KB2511250
                           [37]: KB2511455
                           [38]: KB2515325
                           [39]: KB2518869
                           [40]: KB2519736
                           [41]: KB2522422
                           [42]: KB2524375
                           [43]: KB2529073
                           [44]: KB2532531
                           [45]: KB2533552
                           [46]: KB2533623
                           [47]: KB2534366
                           [48]: KB2536275
                           [49]: KB2536276
                           [50]: KB2539635
                           [51]: KB2541014
                           [52]: KB2544893
                           [53]: KB2545698
                           [54]: KB2547666
                           [55]: KB2552343
                           [56]: KB2555917
                           [57]: KB2556532
                           [58]: KB2560656
                           [59]: KB2562937
                           [60]: KB2563227
                           [61]: KB2563894
                           [62]: KB2564958
                           [63]: KB2567053
                           [64]: KB2567680
                           [65]: KB2570791
                           [66]: KB2570947
                           [67]: KB2572077
                           [68]: KB2574819
                           [69]: KB2579686
                           [70]: KB2584146
                           [71]: KB2585542
                           [72]: KB2588516
                           [73]: KB2603229
                           [74]: KB2604115
                           [75]: KB2607576
                           [76]: KB2607712
                           [77]: KB2616676
                           [78]: KB2617657
                           [79]: KB2618451
                           [80]: KB2619339
                           [81]: KB2620704
                           [82]: KB2620712
                           [83]: KB2621440
                           [84]: KB2631813
                           [85]: KB2633873
                           [86]: KB2633952
                           [87]: KB2639308
                           [88]: KB2639417
                           [89]: KB2640148
                           [90]: KB2641653
                           [91]: KB2641690
                           [92]: KB2644615
                           [93]: KB2645640
                           [94]: KB2647518
                           [95]: KB2647753
                           [96]: KB2653956
                           [97]: KB2654428
                           [98]: KB2655992
                           [99]: KB2656356
                           [100]: KB2656373
                           [101]: KB2656411
                           [102]: KB2658846
                           [103]: KB2659262
                           [104]: KB2660075
                           [105]: KB2660465
                           [106]: KB2660649
                           [107]: KB2661254
                           [108]: KB2665364
                           [109]: KB2667402
                           [110]: KB2676562
                           [111]: KB2677070
                           [112]: KB2679255
                           [113]: KB2685811
                           [114]: KB2685813
                           [115]: KB2685939
                           [116]: KB2686831
                           [117]: KB2688338
                           [118]: KB2690533
                           [119]: KB2691442
                           [120]: KB2695962
                           [121]: KB2698365
                           [122]: KB2699779
                           [123]: KB2705219
                           [124]: KB2709162
                           [125]: KB2709630
                           [126]: KB2709715
                           [127]: KB2709981
                           [128]: KB2712808
                           [129]: KB2718523
                           [130]: KB2718704
                           [131]: KB2719857
                           [132]: KB2719985
                           [133]: KB2724197
                           [134]: KB2726535
                           [135]: KB2727528
                           [136]: KB2729094
                           [137]: KB2729452
                           [138]: KB2731771
                           [139]: KB2731847
                           [140]: KB2732059
                           [141]: KB2732487
                           [142]: KB2732500
                           [143]: KB2735855
                           [144]: KB2736233
                           [145]: KB2736422
                           [146]: KB2739159
                           [147]: KB2741355
                           [148]: KB2742599
                           [149]: KB2743555
                           [150]: KB2749655
                           [151]: KB2750841
                           [152]: KB2753842
                           [153]: KB2756822
                           [154]: KB2756921
                           [155]: KB2757638
                           [156]: KB2758857
                           [157]: KB2761217
                           [158]: KB2761226
                           [159]: KB2762895
                           [160]: KB2763523
                           [161]: KB2769369
                           [162]: KB2770660
                           [163]: KB2773072
                           [164]: KB2778344
                           [165]: KB2778930
                           [166]: KB2779030
                           [167]: KB2779562
                           [168]: KB2785220
                           [169]: KB2786081
                           [170]: KB2786400
                           [171]: KB2789645
                           [172]: KB2790113
                           [173]: KB2790655
                           [174]: KB2791765
                           [175]: KB2798162
                           [176]: KB2799494
                           [177]: KB2799926
                           [178]: KB2800095
                           [179]: KB2803821
                           [180]: KB2804579
                           [181]: KB2807986
                           [182]: KB2808679
                           [183]: KB2808735
                           [184]: KB2809215
                           [185]: KB2809900
                           [186]: KB2813170
                           [187]: KB2813347
                           [188]: KB2813430
                           [189]: KB2813956
                           [190]: KB2820197
                           [191]: KB2820331
                           [192]: KB2823180
                           [193]: KB2823324
                           [194]: KB2829361
                           [195]: KB2830290
                           [196]: KB2832414
                           [197]: KB2833946
                           [198]: KB2834140
                           [199]: KB2834886
                           [200]: KB2835361
                           [201]: KB2835364
                           [202]: KB2836502
                           [203]: KB2836943
                           [204]: KB2839894
                           [205]: KB2840149
                           [206]: KB2840631
                           [207]: KB2843630
                           [208]: KB2844286
                           [209]: KB2845187
                           [210]: KB2845690
                           [211]: KB2846960
                           [212]: KB2847077
                           [213]: KB2847311
                           [214]: KB2847927
                           [215]: KB2849470
                           [216]: KB2850851
                           [217]: KB2852386
                           [218]: KB2853952
                           [219]: KB2857650
                           [220]: KB2859537
                           [221]: KB2861191
                           [222]: KB2861698
                           [223]: KB2861855
                           [224]: KB2862152
                           [225]: KB2862330
                           [226]: KB2862335
                           [227]: KB2862966
                           [228]: KB2862973
                           [229]: KB2863058
                           [230]: KB2863240
                           [231]: KB2864058
                           [232]: KB2864202
                           [233]: KB2868038
                           [234]: KB2868116
                           [235]: KB2868623
                           [236]: KB2868626
                           [237]: KB2868725
                           [238]: KB2871997
                           [239]: KB2872339
                           [240]: KB2875783
                           [241]: KB2876284
                           [242]: KB2876315
                           [243]: KB2876331
                           [244]: KB2882822
                           [245]: KB2883150
                           [246]
Network Card(s):           7 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [02]: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030
                                 Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     192.168.1.254
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.1.75
                                 [02]: fe80::cd94:7835:e04d:8984
                           [03]: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
                                 Connection Name: Bluetooth Network Connection
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [04]: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection 2
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [05]: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection 3
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [06]: Hamachi Network Interface
                                 Connection Name: Hamachi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     25.0.0.1
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 25.45.179.173
                                 [02]: fe80::54c5:b0e:6f37:7d09
                                 [03]: 2620:9b::192d:b3ad
                           [07]: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.56.1
                                 [02]: fe80::80be:d781:3f31:5ad5
```

Here's a [pastebin link to the output of running `driverquery`](http://pastebin.com/MGtHTaQZ) (I can't paste it here because then my post exceeds the 30k character limit).

## The Question

Does anyone have any advice or theories? I'm at my wits' end.

Please let me know in the comments if you need more information.

**Edit:** I neglected to mention that I can still move the mouse cursor, but clicks are ignored. I also *sometimes* get error messages that look like this, but not always:

[image: not responding]

The message goes away if I click either button, but otherwise nothing changes.

Comment: it crashes after a short period of time,and is unusable for a short time? overheating?

Comment: No, it crashes after a random period of time (5 minutes to 2 hours). It is usable immediately after a hard reboot, but will not respond at all until I reboot. A couple of times it has felt overheated, but other times it has not felt warm at all.

Comment: Have you paid any attention to memory/CPU usage? It could be topping out suddenly for some reason and causing the crash.

Comment: I have; I usually watch those pretty closely, anyway. Of course, Task Manager hangs along with everything else, but I have never seen any indications that CPU or RAM usage is topping out right before a crash.

Comment: I would get AutoRuns and disable everything from starting up, if it runs fine ... start adding the services back online until you find it. OTherwise its probably hardware.

Comment: @Logman Yeah, that's the only idea I have left. Unfortunately, that's hard to test because (1) there's no predictable way to trigger the crash and (2) I use this computer heavily for developing software, so it's hard to shut many things down for long.

Comment: This sounds like a HDD that is about to fail.  The pauses are caused by Windows trying to read a file, the HDD unable to do so, so the i/o is flooded with the same request for the same file.

Comment: @Ramhound That's my big fear. Any thoughts on how to confirm this? The drive passes the Dell diagnostics I have run on it and didn't throw up any problems when defragging, either.

Comment: Use tools other then Dells?  There are tons of S.M.A.R.T tools out there.  One way to confirm its a problem, boot into a minimal boot configuration, if that helps that normally means its a software not hardware problem

Comment: I used CrystalDiskInfo; it reports no HDD problems.

Comment: try all steps from scenario 3 of this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

Somehow, the page file had been disabled; I have no idea how that happened.  This was apparently causing my system to run out of memory and crash.

I still don't understand why it ran out of memory in some instances. Sometimes, I could see my memory usage in the Task Manager right before it went down, and it was rarely above 75% RAM usage. I have 8GB RAM, and typical usage for me is in the 70-90% range, so there's nothing unusual about that. Sometimes, it crashed even with nothing running other than core system processes and a handful of services.

Anyway, enabling the page file and letting Windows manage it automatically seems to have fixed the problem; I have had no crashes since then (still true as of December 23, 2014).